# Multiple sites with same DB good idea?

Tags: mysql

I am planning to setup a different websites with same DB server(mysql). What i want to know is, Is it a good idea to do that?

Comment: It was a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the DB is able to handle the load, then it's not a bad idea in many cases. If it can't do this, it's obviously a lousy idea.

Since you don't give any useful information regarding your projects, that's about all that can be said about the subject.